# Change font size of Segmented Control in React native

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, react-native

How can I customize font size and font family in segmented control in React Native?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is not implemented yet in the API. Maybe ask for it on [Github](http://github.com/facebook/react-native)

You can change the props defined in [RN's doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/segmentedcontrolios.html) only at the moment.

You can stil change the style directly in react-native's module files but it will disappear with every update.